# FTP server not sending data to proxy in Python with sockets

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, ftp, wireshark

I'm building a proxy in Python between a ftp client and a ftp server. All the control phase and data phase is well done (currently on active mode), but when I send the request (LIST, for example), server does not send the information back. I don't know what is causing this fault...

Here is the Wireshark capture:

[image: Wireshark capture]

And the corresponding code:

```
print(f"Waiting for a message from the server to the PORT message")
answer = fw_proxy_server.recv(BUFFER_FTP)
print(answer) # 200 PORT command successful
fw_proxy_client.send(answer) # forward to client

# Create the socket to listen on 192.168.30.80:port (IP_PROXY:port)
server_socket2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket2.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str(INTERFACE_PROXY_SERVER + '\0').encode('utf-8'))
server_socket2.bind((IP_PROXY, port))
server_socket2.listen()

print(f"Waiting for a message from the client")
message = fw_proxy_client.recv(BUFFER_FTP) # REQUEST: LIST

print(f"Forwarding message from the server")
message = send(fw_proxy_server, "LIST") # REQUEST: LIST (sent to port 21)

# Accept an incoming connection from the Server with data

server_socket2, data_address = server_socket2.accept() # HERE PROGRAM HANG
print(f"Data connection from {data_address} has been established!")

print(f"Waiting for a message from the data from server")
message = fw_proxy_server.recv(BUFFER_FTP) # never executed
```

The IPs are the following:
Client: 192.168.40.50
Proxy-client: 192.168.40.80
Proxy-server: 192.168.30.80
Server: 192.168.30.90

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Changed order of listening to port, so that the port is listened before sending the PORT command and the LIST request. Same result, connection refused:

```
start = str(message).find("(")
end = str(message).find(")")
tuple = str(message)[start+1:end].split(',')
port = int(tuple[4])*256 + int(list(filter(str.isdigit, tuple[5]))[0])
#Create the socket to listen on 192.168.40.80:port
server_socket2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket2.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str(INTERFACE_PROXY_SERVER + '\0').encode('utf-8'))
server_socket2.bind(("192.168.40.80", port)) # With 192.168.30.80 it doesn't work too
server_socket2.listen()

answer = send(fw_proxy_server, "PORT 192,168,30,80," + tuple[4] + "," + tuple[5])
print(f"Waiting for a message from the server to the PORT message")
print(answer) # 200 PORT command successful
fw_proxy_client.send(answer)

#Create the socket to forward the data to the server

print(f"Waiting for a request from the client") # REQUEST: LIST
message = fw_proxy_client.recv(BUFFER_FTP)
print(message)

fw_proxy_server.send(message)
print(f"Waiting for an answer from the server") # Response 425: Unable to build data connection: Connection refused
answer = fw_proxy_server.recv(BUFFER_FTP)
print(answer)


#Accept an incoming connection from the Client
server_socket2, data_address = server_socket2.accept() #Program hang
print(f"Data connection from {data_address} has been established!")

print(f"Waiting for a message from the server")
print(answer)
```

Comment: Well, it is clear as crystal that FTP server was unable to establish data-connection, reason being connection refused (from wireshark capture). But in the current state nothing can be deduced ! Dont just paste snippets of code. Code has a proper execution sequence, see [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But my initial thoughts on the problem are assuming you are just forwarding the PORT message of ftp client from proxy server to ftp server, ftp server would try to connect to client which is behind proxy hence connection refused

Comment: No, that is already taken into account and that PORT message only contains de proxy IP so that the server could contact it.

Comment: My bad, I didnt observe the initial sequence of PORT successful message. Well in that case, the only immediate fault I can see is you are opening data-connection port in proxy server after sending the PORT command (implication: may be server would have tried to connect to it before you actually opened the port !) , So try having the code for data-connection port before sending PORT command

Comment: I am not sure though when does ftp server connects, as soon as you send the PORT command or after sending the LIST ? Do you have any thoughts ?

Comment: After a test run... It seems to connect after the LIST command not after the PORT command

Comment: thanks, question updated to reflect that change of order. But still the same result... I really have no clue of what could I be missing...

Comment: Are you sure that the port you are sending and the port you are listening on are the same ? (that is why [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required) I am doubtful about ``tuple[4]`` and ``tuple[5]``. But in any case the port ``server_socket2`` in binding ``i.e, port`` should be equal to ``256*tuple[4] + tuple[5]``. Is it the case ? Pls, provide full code, that really helps in investigating better.

Comment: And moreover, if you are using ``setsockopt`` for binding to interfere that is not required, bind make sures that it only listens on interface with that particular IP.

Comment: You are right, the filter and list commands were not tested properly... If you write an answer I will be glad to accept it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wireshark capture session, it sounds like the port you are sending to the FTP server and the port you are actually listening for data-connection on the proxy-server are not same hence FTP server reporting connection refused. Make sure the port `server_socket2` is binding i.e, `port` is equal to `256 * tuple[4] + tuple[5]`. I believe the socket_option `25` refers to `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, in that case when you are binding the socket using `bind()` then there is no need to explicitly bind the socket to interface (in general use case). Can you remove that line and check if it is still working ? It will be a learning for me too ! Thanks.

Comment: The problem was mainly related with the port, and yes, it seems to work without specifying the interface. Very useful answer.